# Regex to match and validate internet media type?

Tags: regex, validation, media

I want to validate internet types input via my API.

Can you help writing a regex to match?

Example types below from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

```
application/atom+xml
application/EDI-X12
application/xml-dtd
application/zip
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
video/quicktime
```

Must meet standard:

```
type / media type name [+suffix]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really straightforward:

`\w+/[-+.\w]+`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/oH5bS7/1

And if you want to validate there's at most one `+`:

`\w+/[-.\w]+(?:\+[-.\w]+)?`

Comment: This does not match `*` in either part

Answer (score 9):

I recently had a need to validate media types a bit more strictly than the existing answers.  Here's what I came up with, based on the intersection of the [grammar from RFC 2045 Section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1) and [RFC 7231 Section 3.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1) (which disallows `{}` in tokens and whitespace except between parameters).  For a C-like language with `(?:)` non-capturing groups:

```
ows = "[ \t]*";
token = "[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+.^_`|~-]+";
quotedString = "\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\.)*\"";
type = "(application|audio|font|example|image|message|model|multipart|text|video|x-(?:" + token + "))";
parameter = ";" + ows + token + "=" + "(?:" + token + "|" + quotedString + ")";
mediaType = type + "/" + "(" + token + ")((?:" + ows + parameter + ")*)";
```

This ends up with a rather monstrous

```
"(application|audio|font|example|image|message|model|multipart|text|video|x-(?:[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+.^_`|~-]+))/([0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+.^_`|~-]+)((?:[ \t]*;[ \t]*[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+.^_`|~-]+=(?:[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+.^_`|~-]+|\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\.)*\"))*)"
```

which captures type, subtype, and parameters, or just

```
"(application|audio|font|example|image|message|model|multipart|text|video|x-(?:[0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+.^_`|~-]+))/([0-9A-Za-z!#$%&'*+.^_`|~-]+)"
```

omitting parameters.  Note that these could be made more forward-compatible (and less strict) by allowing any `token` for `type` (as RFC 7231 does) rather than limiting to "application", "audio", etc.

In practice you may want to additionally limit inputs to [IANA Registered Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) or [mailcap](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mime-support/mailcap.5.en.html) or specific types appropriate for your application based on intended use.

Answer (score 1):

A more general regex with support of parameter is:

```
(?P<main>\w+|\*)/(?P<sub>\w+|\*)(\s*;\s*(?P<param>\w+)=\s*=\s*(?P<val>\S+))?
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lQ3rX4/2

Comment: Note there's an extra `=` in the parameter match expression that prevents this from working properly.

Comment: the demo shows this RegExp does not match many of the examples (those containing `.` or `-` or `+`)

Comment: This regex does not match multitple parameters