# Regex to validate and capture sub components from Internet Media Type

Tags: c#, .net, regex, mime-types, media-type

### Here's the question that was already posted: [Regex to match and validate internet media type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201083/regex-to-match-and-validate-internet-media-type)

This works, for sure But **fails** in some of these:

```
*/plain
text/-vnd.MS.office-document.WORD+xml-
text/-vnd.MS.office_document.WORD+xml.
text/.vnd.MS.office_document.WORD+xml-
text/.vnd.MS.office-document.WORD+xml.
text/-api-format
text/.api.format
text/.api-format
text/-api.format
text/api-format-
text/api.format.+json
text/api-for_mat.
text/api.format-+json
text/api.-for_mat
text/api-.format+json
```

The Regex **must not match** the above mentioned string.

But **must match** the following string

```
*/*
text/*
image/jpg
image/x.apng+png
image/x-jpg2000+jpg
text/api.format
text/api-format+json
text/prs.NIRIN.config+xml
text/vnd.MS.office-document.WORD+xml
```

I'm a novice in Regex but I came up with this:

```
^(?<Base>application|audio|example|image|message|model|multipart|text|video)/(?<Extension>prs\.|vnd\.|x\.|x-)?(?<Sub>[\w-[_]]+(?:[.-]?[\w-[_]]+)*)+(?:\+(?<Super>[\w-[_]]+))?$
```

But it matches only a subset and matches a non-match too!!

But I want it like this:

```
Base: *, <any of the above 'Base'>
Extension: prs. , vnd. , x. , x- <legacy types, optional>
Sub: MS.office-document.WORD <if it contains nested types like this>
    Capture 1: MS
    Capture 2: office-document
    Capture 2: WORD
Super: xml <optional, rules same as 'Base' types and captures of 'Sub'>
```

> Am I doing something wrong here?
>
> Will it be too complex?
>
> Can we simplify it further even with the proposed rules?
>
> **Note:** this is `.net` flavored regex. so we can use `.net` specific features too!

Thanks.

Comment: Also should _match_ the media types from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7161265/5707707)